# Check if userform open

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I run a program which repeats itself. It should stop, when the user closes the userform. It runs without stopping.

Since the program calls itself every 8 seconds, I want to check at the end if the userform is still loaded / opened.

```
Public Sub NextPicture1()
   PictureChange = Now + TimeValue("00:00:08")
   If Onboarding_Projekt.Visible = True Then
      Application.OnTime PictureChange, "NextPicture1"
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a function like this:

```
Public Function IsLoaded(formName As String) As Boolean
Dim frm As Object
For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
    If frm.Name = formName Then
        IsLoaded = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next frm
IsLoaded = False
End Function
```

Usage:

```
If IsLoaded("Form_Test") Then
    'Do Something
End If
```

Your code should look like this:

```
Public Sub NextPicture1()
   PictureChange = Now + TimeValue("00:00:08")
   If IsLoaded("Onboarding_Projekt") Then
      Application.OnTime PictureChange, "NextPicture1"
   End If
End Sub

Public Function IsLoaded(formName As String) As Boolean
    Dim frm As Object
    For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
        If frm.Name = formName Then
            IsLoaded = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next frm
    IsLoaded = False
End Function
```

Comment: I am still working on it. My Problem is, that I am not that good with functions and I am not sure how to implement it. - If I use your second part and change the "Form_Test" with "Onboarding_Projekt" it works, but the loop still goes on. What do I need to change in the Function besides Copy-Paste it in my Code? (Sry for my inexperience); best regards

Comment: @Lutscha Answer edited, the last code block should work for you

Comment: So far I can see that it goes throgh the function, but even if nothing is opened, your function still sets the IsLoaded function on true. And thats the exact point, where I want to leave the sub and end my loop.

Comment: @Lutscha the code works fine for me. It stops calling the NextPicture1() Sub when the UserForm is closed.

Comment: @Lutscha, I had the same problem. I realised though, instead of passing the form name as the string i.e. `IsLoaded("Onboarding_Projekt")` , I was passing the form name like this: `IsLoaded(Onboarding_Projekt.name)`. The problem here is that it has to initialise the form to get the name, which defeated the purpose!. Using the string instead resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that shows both whether it's loaded and whether it's visible:

```
Function Userform_Check( _
    form_name As String) _
        As Integer

    ' Returns:
    '   0 - Userform is not loaded
    '   1 - Loaded but not visible
    '   2 - Loaded and visible

    ' mUtilities.Userform_Check()

    Dim frm As Object

    Userform_Check = 0

    For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
        If frm.name = form_name Then
            Userform_Check = 1

            If frm.Visible Then Userform_Check = 2

            Exit For
        End If
    Next frm

' Function Userform_Check( _
    form_name As String) _
        As Integer
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a field that should help identify it easily:

```
  If userform.Visible = True Then
      'do something
  End If
```

Comment: This code will cause the form to load. That's why we need workarounds.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me using if userform.visible = false then userform.show. This prevented loading the form to center screen every time.