# Excel Check User form is Open

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm not an experienced coder, so please excuse the simplistic nature of this request. I have a userform in excel to add a client. Which is also accessible from the main dashboard.

If the 'Add Client' Form is accessed through the Value GW Form ("UF_ValueGW_v4), then when adding the client it writes into the relevant field within the form. However if the 'Add Client' Form is accessed via the dashboard then the it ignores writing to the Value GW Form.

The code that I have written either errors out, or it will open the form and add the text. The code that I have used is:

```
Private Sub CmdB_Previous_Click()

Dim wTracker As Workbook
Dim xClientData
Dim cRow
Dim lClientData

Set wTracker = ThisWorkbook
Set xClientData = wTracker.Worksheets("ClientData")

cRow = xClientData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

xClientData.Range("A" & cRow).Value = Me.TB_ClientName.Text

If IsLoaded("UF_ValueGW_v4") Then
    UF_ValueGW_v4.CB_Client.Text = Me.TB_ClientName.Text
End If

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Could anyone provide me some assistance and advice on this please?

Comment: Pls elaborate on `the code errors out`. Maybe you could [edit] your question and add some screenshots

Comment: If this form is intended to work with the other form, why would you launch it directly?

Comment: Yes sorry, when I run the Debug the Private Sub CmdB_Previous_Click() is highlighted. However if I mark out the:

'If IsLoaded("UF_ValueGW_v4") Then
    UF_ValueGW_v4.CB_Client.Text = Me.TB_ClientName.Text
'End If

Then the code works, but if the other Userform is not open it opens it and adds the text into the CB_Client field which is shouldn't do.

Comment: @TimWilliams It is meant to work independently, but if we were completing the data in the Value GW Form and haven't got the Client in the list we can add the client in without having to lose the data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563719/check-if-userform-open

Comment: @TimWilliams I did read this thread, but couldn't get it to work. I'll try it again, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments, I'm not sure why this didn't work previously. But the code if now working:

```
Private Sub CmdB_AddClient_Click()

Dim wTracker As Workbook
Dim xClientData
Dim cRow
Dim lClientData

Set wTracker = ThisWorkbook
Set xClientData = wTracker.Worksheets("ClientData")

cRow = xClientData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

xClientData.Range("A" & cRow).Value = Me.TB_ClientName.Text

If IsLoaded("UF_ValueGW_v4") Then
    UF_ValueGW_v4.CB_Client.Text = Me.TB_ClientName.Text
End If

Unload Me

End Sub

Public Function IsLoaded(formName As String) As Boolean
    Dim frm As Object
    For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
        If frm.Name = formName Then
            IsLoaded = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next frm
    IsLoaded = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This Function does the job, by testing a Property that is only available when the UserForm is loaded:

```
    Function fnIsLoaded(strUserFormName As String) As Boolean
    Dim objFrm As Object
    Dim strDummy As String
    Dim intForm As Integer

    On Error GoTo lblErr_UserFormNotLoaded

    For intForm = 1 To UserForms.Count
        Set objFrm = UserForms(intForm)
        If objFrm.Name = strUserFormName Then
            strDummy = objFrm.ActiveControl.Name
            fnIsLoaded = True
            GoTo lblExit_Success
        End If
        Set objFrm = Nothing
    Next

lblExit_Success:
    Exit Function

lblErr_UserFormNotLoaded:
    fnIsLoaded = False

End Function
```