# AutoKeys in Access VBA to Open/Close a form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've created a form called frm_autokeys where the user is given an bunch of options such as export to Word, export to Excel etc (All of these functions work).

I want the form to open and close when the user presses F4. I've wrote a macro (hate them would rather have this in VBA code if there's a way?) called AutoKeys to have the form open but can't write an if statement to check if the form is open or not in order to call the close function for the form.

Has anyone worked out a way to do this?

Comment: Might want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563719/check-if-userform-open), especially the `If frm.Visible Then` which you can pair with `frm.Hide` if that's what you intend to do.

Comment: @Notus_Panda That's about user forms, not about Access forms (these are very different) and about VBA, not about Access macros

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't want to add it this way as it would mean adding the code or calling the function in every form, whereas using the macro it's project wide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by checking if the form is loaded, and using an `If` block with an `Else` block:

Open an `If` block.

```
Condition: CurrentProject.AllForms!frm_autokeys.IsLoaded
Action: CloseWindow Form frm_autokeys

Else block connected to If block
Action: OpenForm frm_autokeys
```

The [AXL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49487686/7296893):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<UserInterfaceMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
    <UserInterfaceMacro MinimumClientDesignVersion="14.0.0000.0000">
        <Statements />
        <Sub Name="{F4}">
            <Statements>
                <ConditionalBlock>
                    <If>
                        <Condition>[CurrentProject].[AllForms]![frm_autokeys].[IsLoaded]</Condition>
                        <Statements>
                            <Action Name="CloseWindow">
                                <Argument Name="ObjectType">Form</Argument>
                                <Argument Name="ObjectName">frm_autokeys</Argument>
                            </Action>
                        </Statements>
                    </If>
                    <Else>
                        <Statements>
                            <Action Name="OpenForm">
                                <Argument Name="FormName">frm_autokeys</Argument>
                            </Action>
                        </Statements>
                    </Else>
                </ConditionalBlock>
            </Statements>
        </Sub>
    </UserInterfaceMacro>
</UserInterfaceMacros>
```

Of course, you can defer to VBA by using the `RunCode` action in macros, but you can't directly handle keypresses in VBA (without a lot of hackery, that is, since VBA can use WinAPI anything is possible)

Comment: You're an absolute star, that AXL code works perfectly. I didn't know you could write code for the Macro and just paste it in. Thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks! Note that you don't need to write AXL, you can copy it from macros (Ctrl + A then Ctrl + C in the macro body, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49586432/7296893). AXL is very verbose, strict, and hard to debug, so I rarely modify it directly beyond simple find & replaces of names. It's mostly just for sharing macros.